# Revolut account and taxation

Tags: taxes, european-union, revolut

I have one account from Revolut and one account from my Country (EU). 
Some friends will send me some money in revolut for a job.

- At the end of the year, I have to report this money for taxation or is safe?
- Revolut gives a report by name or by TAX ID to my Country (EU) for people to avoid taxes?

Comment: The EU is not a country, and tax law likely varies from country to country. Chances are you should absolutely count this as income, though.

Comment: The transfer is not what is taxable.  Doing paid work is what is taxable.  The income is exactly as taxable regardless of whether you use Revolut for the transfer, a bank wire, suitcases of cash, or any other method.  (Crossing international borders with suitcases of cash may require more paperwork... but that is a separate issue from taxation)

Comment: Is the OP asking how to commit tax fraud?

Comment: @ceejayoz I interpreted OP's statement as "my country which is within the EU". Yes, EU is still missing a central tax regulation/service comparable to US IRS. Indeed they have developed a fully working distributed exchange systems between LRS-es (Local Revenue Services)

Answer (score 3):

As per the law (your country's), you have to declare your income. Not doing that is fraud and it will carry some sort of punishment. That being said, yes, Revolut will share your info (also per the law), and they say it in their terms:

> We also share your personal information with fraud-prevention agencies to check your identity, protect against fraud, keep to anti-money-laundering laws and confirm that you are eligible to use our products and services.

Comment: Revolut must obey to the CRS (Common Reporting Standard): [OECD](http://www.oecd.org/tax/automatic-exchange/crs-implementation-and-assistance/tax-identification-numbers/), [an article from ING Netherlands](https://www.ing.com/web/file?uuid=2f619593-3d31-4bdd-9651-bf550aaae197&owner=b03bc017-e0db-4b5d-abbf-003b12934429&contentid=46679)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should create a business account in Revolut for receiving money for a job. Otherwise there is a chance Revolut will block your account and you will have to explain/prove the income.